# Cannot run node.js program in command prompt

Tags: node.js

Arch-noobie here. When I try to run a node.js program in windows command prompt by stating its location, it will invariably say "[stated location] is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

In all answers to similar questions, in all node.js manuals, it is assumed you can just run a node.js file by calling it from its location. There will always be the suggestion of trying some "hello world" example BEFORE establishing a server and so on.

Even if I clean the command prompt with "prompt $ cmd", and then write the whole location manually, I get the same message.

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you typing your location? What command are you typing in cmd?

Comment: Run `echo %path%` in the command prompt and post the output.

Comment: In cmd I am typing: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\00.js" (00.js is the script I want to run)

Comment: Since I followed the directions from the answer below, when I run "echo %path%" I get "C:\Program Files\nodejs\bin"

Answer (score 1):

By default, your node.js should be installed in `C:\Program Files\nodejs` location. Check for it.

Next, look for environment variables to be set at `C:\Program Files\nodejs\bin`
You can follow this [link](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) to check for the PATH and environment variables.

Then, restart your system. It should start working.

Comment: Node is installed in "C:\Program Files\nodejs". I followed the directions form the link to set the path, and it is set. But now I get "'Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, etc."

Comment: is `node -v` giving you the version??

Comment: Yes, it does. v6.10.3

Comment: That means you can run node.js program in command prompt now. Try with `node filename.js`

Comment: This is the result of trying to run it, before cleaning the command prompt:

Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 6.10.3 (x64) and npm.

C:\Users\algunillo>node a00.js
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\algunillo\a00.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:505:3

Comment: The same message appeared when trying to run it (node a00.js) after cleaning the command prompt with "prompt $ cmd"

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are typing node NOT npm

Comment: node filename NOT npm filename

Comment: Based on their issue, "is not recognized as an internal or external command" this is likely a path issue and completely unrelated to typing npm instead of node.